# How to increment score inside for each loop in unity?

Tags: c#, loops, unity-game-engine, increment

I am using foreach loop to check answers entered by user to given 5 multiplication questions. (using instance to display 5 questions on start)

Now i an trying to add score counter and increment it by 1 if answer is correct and depending on score i will display stars .for example, if score is less than 3 then 1 star, if 4 then 2 stars and if 5 then 3 stars. I am getting only one star even if all answers are correct. Can anyone possibly tell me how to achieve this please?

I tried adding score++ inside if statement. but it does not increment score value.

```
public void CheckButton() 
{
    int answer;

    foreach (TestModeQuestionUI _TestModeQuestionUIRefrence in testModeQuestionExampleList)
    {
        answer = _TestModeQuestionUIRefrence.GetAnswerInputField();

        if ((_TestModeQuestionUIRefrence.a * _TestModeQuestionUIRefrence.b) == answer)
        {
            _TestModeQuestionUIRefrence.SetResultOfAnswerInputField(1);
            score++;
        }
        else
        {
            _TestModeQuestionUIRefrence.SetResultOfAnswerInputField(2);
        }
    }

    roundCompletePanel.SetActive(true);
    CheckHowManyStars();

    ShowRoundCompletePanel(score);
}
```

Comment: Put a break point on the statement score++ and see if you are reaching the break point.  We can't tell if the answer is never correct or if the score++ is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just assuming here that

```
(_TestModeQuestionUIRefrence.a * _TestModeQuestionUIRefrence.b) == answer
```

are all `float` values. **Never** compare `float` directly using `==`. They might never be equal even though logically they should. They might differ by a very small "epsilon" due to [Floating point precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-precision_floating-point_format).

---

Use [`Mathf.Approximately`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Approximately.html) instead which uses exactly that small "epsilon" for its equality definition.

```
if (Mathf.Approximately(_TestModeQuestionUIRefrence.a * _TestModeQuestionUIRefrence.b, answer))
```

It is similar to

```
if (_TestModeQuestionUIRefrence.a * _TestModeQuestionUIRefrence.b - answer <= diferenceSmallEnoughThreshold)
```

where `differenceSmallEnoughThreshold` would be a defined threshold to use for euality

Comment: ok i will use Mathf.Approximately here. and what is mean by adding break point can you please explain if possible?

Comment: what jdweng refers to is Debugging e.g. using [VisualStudio](https://learn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019)

Comment: using Mathf.Approximately has solved score increment issue. Thank you very much

Comment: well if you are serious about making this game come alive, you better spend some time looking into that infamous "breakpoint" stuff!

Comment: @MKougiouris yes I use debug. log but sorry I didn't know what is it called. Now i Know.

Comment: we don't refer to `Debug.Log` but debugging using breakpoints .. it is essential if you want to debug your code properly without spamming in `Debug.Log` everywhere

Comment: Debug.Log will print something for you. A "breakpoint" stops execution of the program so that you can go line by line if needed and look at everything going on. Do look it up!

Comment: @Sarita https://unity3d.com/de/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/debugging-unity-games-visual-studio

Comment: @derHugo thank you for the link. i will have look at it

Comment: @ MKougiouris ok now i understand difference between  using break points and just debugging .thanks